# How can I avoid from being see the thick rectangle around a control when selecting the control at run time when the application is running?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is not my control I downloaded it from this page :

[Advanced TrackBar](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14378/Advanced-TrackBar-Slider-Control-with-MAC-Style-C)

Then I dragged it to form1 designer from the toolbox.

When the application is running and I use the trackBar at some point it's like I selected the control and it's showing the selected rectangle around it.

and if I select/use another control at runtime the rectangle around the trackBar still exist.

[image: Rectangle like selecting the control but at run time]

Comment: It is the focus rectangle, users that prefer the keyboard over the mouse to operate the UI need it.  Commenting out the call to ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle() ought to suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the `OnPaint` override method in the MACTrackBar.cs file, comment out these lines:

```
// Draws a focus rectangle
// if(this.Focused)
//   ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, 
//                                   Rectangle.Inflate(this.ClientRectangle, -2, -2));
```